# What is a Application startup file and what should be loaded when using a react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

When creating a nodeJS application, it asks of me an "Application startup file"

I can't seem to figure out something that wont make my application 503 and its the only one that I think might be wrong and any help I found elsewhere on the internet and the only defenition I found was "Application startup file - the initial file that will be processed when launching the application." Which is basically just resaying the same thing as the label in other words.

So what is the Application startup file in a nodeJS project, and what should be loaded while working in a React App (app.js/jsx? Index.html? the server js file that loads babel?)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Think of Node as your webserver that processes your data and React as you client frontend.

Your node application startup file needs to be either a Typescript (*.ts) or Javascript (*.js) file.

What you currently have in the field is a *.jsx file which is a react file for rendering html in javascript.

You should be looking to have an index.js file there. If you want to know what goes into that index.js file, you can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/introduction-to-nodejs/)

Comment: But thats what i'm not understanding, what is that file? the index.html in public? the index.js at the root of react that loads everything or the server/index.js that is the config with babel and everything for server side react? Also, .jsx and .tsx are not allowed?

Comment: A Node server and ReactJS are two completely different things. Usually when you make a site you want a server to handle requests like signing in, getting data from a server etc. An API essentially, it can also serve html if need be. Node and React are completely independent of each other.

You could use Node but I guess you are using an application which tries to initialize them both for you.

Answer (score 0):

> But that's what I'm not understanding, what is that file? the index.html in public? The index.js at the root of React that loads everything or the server/index.js that is the config with babel and everything for server side react? Also, .jsx and .tsx are not allowed?

Right, `.jsx` and `.tsx` is not allowed because it's asking for an **Application startup file**. In React that would be the `bundle.js` file that is part of the startup process and that file would contain the following:

1. Instructions to find the div with id of 'root' in the DOM
2. Instructions to tell React to take control of that element
3. Instructions to tell React to get JSX from the App component, turn it into HTML, and show it in the root

Regarding the first two, it goes into **index.html** and it looks something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regarding the last instructions, it's grabbing a **bundle.js** file. Well, it's not really called bundle.js but more like `lkjhghjkiuyuhjiuj.js` and it runs code that is in `index.js` that may look something like this:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
const root = createRoot(rootElement)

root.render(<App />)
```